# Activity Recognition Api Diagram

Tags: android, activity-recognition, diagramming

I have done my thesis and now I have to make a presentation.
The professor asked me for diagramms at every api that I used.

So the only api that I don't have the diagramm is the Activity recognition api

Could anyone please help me, because I don't know how to draw it and I can't find something on the internet?

Comment: Wish you all the best for your thesis, what type of diagram you required ?
do you required recognition api flow diagram ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your wish.
it would be better if the diagram will be sequence diagramm.
But if you can do it in flow diagram, im ok with that

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=recognition+api+diagram&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip1qb6vdjdAhVR0RoKHR0RABQQsAR6BAgAEAE&biw=1600&bih=789#imgrc=_ Check this link it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you my friend, but i cant find something on the net and i ve been looking 2 days now